# Returning millions of records from api response laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a requirement where i am supposed to return millions of records from my database when an api endpoint is being called. As per requirement, pagination is being done on the frontend so returning paginated data is not an option. I have tried this;

```
$this->employee_records = DB::table('master_data')->select(DB::raw("employee_number, first_name, middle_name, last_name, ministry, grade, original_date_of_hire, provider_name, pfa_name, date_of_birth"))->orderBy('first_name')->cursor();
```

But the load time is still in minutes. How can i optimize this? Thanks

Comment: Millions of records within minutes is probably as good as you can get. The only part that can be optimized is to remove the `orderBy` if that is possible or ensure that `first_name` has an index if you need to use the ordering. Other than that paying for better hardware is the only way to improve performance after that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can give try to ElasticSearch, it can get job done faster, if not fastest!

https://www.elastic.co/